# scale_colour_discrete doesn't work when reproducing an example in R cookbook

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to reproduce an example here [R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/) that specifies both color and shape in the legend.

The original code is

```
# A different data set
df2 <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
  time = factor(rep(c(1,2),2), levels=c(1,2)),
  total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)

# A basic graph
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, group=sex, shape=sex)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_discrete(name  ="Payer",
                          breaks=c("Female", "Male"),
                          labels=c("Woman", "Man")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name  ="Payer",
                       breaks=c("Female", "Male"),
                       labels=c("Woman", "Man"))
```

I don't want the line, so I commented out the part `geom_line()+`. The points don't have color anymore. Could anyone help with this?

```
# A different data set
df2 <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
  time = factor(rep(c(1,2),2), levels=c(1,2)),
  total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)

# A basic graph
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, group=sex, shape=sex)) + 
#  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_discrete(name  ="Payer",
                          breaks=c("Female", "Male"),
                          labels=c("Woman", "Man")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name  ="Payer",
                       breaks=c("Female", "Male"),
                       labels=c("Woman", "Man"))
```

Comment: It seems you are missing the `colour` aesthetic in your code, so none of the two versions should have colours in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your code chunks are missing the `colour` aesthetic, which would be required to colour your geometries according to the categorical variable.

You can also simplify the code: using the `colour` aesthetic or removing the line geometry makes the `group` aesthetic superfluous:

```r
# A different data set
df2 <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
  time = factor(rep(c(1,2),2), levels=c(1,2)),
  total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)
library(ggplot2)
# A basic graph
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, shape=sex, colour=sex)) + 
  # geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_discrete(name  ="Payer",
                        breaks=c("Female", "Male"),
                        labels=c("Woman", "Man")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name  ="Payer",
                       breaks=c("Female", "Male"),
                       labels=c("Woman", "Man"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That works, thank you! Do you by any chance know how to remove some of the labels of x axis when there are too many of them? In this example I tried ```+ scale_x_discrete(labels= c(NA,2))``` , but it only shows the word NA.

Comment: You can try using an empty string, like so: `scale_x_discrete(labels = c("", 2))`
However, it might be a sturdier solution to use the built-in option ggplot2 has, see for example the new options `guide_axis()` offers: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#rewrite-of-axis-code